# MoPub SDK : how to remove the video ads ?

Tags: android, ios, admob, ads, mopub

I use the MoPub SDK (through AdMob mediation, and on Android, but certainly do not change the answer to the question) and I want to have only classic interstitial (no video ads).

How can I do ?

Answer (score 1):

Under your Marketplace settings, there is a section called "Fullscreen Ad Unit Settings". Here you can select "All Fullscreen Formats Except Video Ads". Please see the screenshot in MoPub's document Marketplace Setup.

https://dev.twitter.com/mopub/marketplace/setup

Please note that this only turns off video ads for MoPub's Marketplace and not third party ad networks. If you would like a purely video free ad unit in MoPub, you would have to also disable video ads on each respective ad network you have enabled under that ad unit as well.

Comment: any idea how to disable MarketPlace video ads just for one ad unit